# change canvas filltext text with setInterval

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval

I designed a counter with canvas.Everything goes fine in design but when I want to change the time number and refresh it by setInterval,filltext start creates over itself and it change it's position.
code sample is here:

```
<canvas id="top-left" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("top-left");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.06);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.97);
ctx.arc(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.97,canvas.width * 0.91,1*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI);
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.97);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width * 0.06,canvas.height * 0.97);
ctx.shadowBlur = canvas.width * 0.016;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = canvas.width * 0.016;
ctx.shadowColor = "#666666";    
ctx.fillStyle = "#98ae32";
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = canvas.width * 0.01;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.stroke();

var x = 1;  
var c = setInterval(function(){
    ctx.font = canvas.width * 0.273 + "px Baskerville Old Face";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillText(x,canvas.width * 0.33,canvas.height * 0.86);   
    x++;
    if(x === 5){
        clearInterval(c);   
    }
},1000);
</script>
```

I want to know how can I change the filltext text without creating over itself.I just want to update text.Please help me to solve my problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to draw a set of words on your arc**

First make your code reusable:

1. Put your texts in an array: `var texts=['Hello','World','Coding','is','Fun!'];`
2. Put your arc path commands in a function (for easy reuse).
3. Put your text drawing commands in a function (for easy reuse).

And then create an animation loop that does these:

4. Clear the canvas.
5. Draw your arc.
6. Draw the next text.
7. If there are more texts, repeat with #4.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var i=0;
var texts=['Hello','World','Coding','is','Fun!'];
var nextTime=0;
var duration=1000;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  if(time<nextTime){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); return;}
  nextTime+=duration;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  drawArc();
  drawText(texts[i]);
  i++;
  if(i<texts.length){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }
}

function drawText(text){
  var px=canvas.width*0.273;
  ctx.font = px + "px Baskerville Old Face";
  ctx.textAlign='right';
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillText(text,canvas.width-15,canvas.height * 0.86);  
}

function drawArc(){
  ctx.beginPath();    
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.06);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.97);
  ctx.arc(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.97,canvas.width * 0.91,1*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI);
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width * 0.97,canvas.height * 0.97);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width * 0.06,canvas.height * 0.97);
  ctx.shadowBlur = canvas.width * 0.016;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = canvas.width * 0.016;
  ctx.shadowColor = "#666666";    
  ctx.fillStyle = "#98ae32";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = canvas.width * 0.01;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=175 height=175></canvas>
```